# Erro ao carregar fonts no build do Vue (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Estou fazendo o `build` do meu projeto, e todo o sistema está carregando, menos as fontes do `iview`, no modo `dev` tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas ao gerar o `build` as fontes ficam com uns **quadrados** e no `console` já me vem o erro...

> ```
> >  http://192.168.56.1:8080/Tpc/static/css/static/fonts/ionicons.05acfdb.woff
> > net::ERR_ABORTED
> ```

A questão é clara, ele esta adicionando a pasta `static/css/static` sendo que só deveria ser `static/css` (pelo menos é o que acho) e isso só acontece com essas fonts, o resto está tudo funcionando, estou usando o `iview` (que o **Sergio** daqui da comunidade me indicou e achei incrivel).

A questão é, preciso fazer alguma configuração diferente o meu `webpack`?

Comment: Oi Rafael, só agora reparei nesta pergunta... :( conseguiste resolver?

Comment: @Sergio Opa, sem problemas, não consegui resolver ainda cara

Comment: Podes reproduzir isso no github?